# How to declare and call nested interfaces in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to convert JavaScript to TypeScript. I was looking for answers on the subject of "recursive" or "nested" interfaces and the like, but found no useful or understandable answer.

The following structure steadfastly opposed my previous attempts:

```
interface iROGeneric<T> {
    readonly [key: string]: T | iROGeneric<T>;
};

const Html: iROGeneric<HTMLElement> = {
    body: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body"),
    head: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("head"),
    article: {
        main: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("main > article"),
        aside: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("aside > article")
    }
}
```

When I try to access individual object elements, e.g.

```
Html.main.insertAdjacentHTML(...);
```

I get the following error during compile.time:

> Property 'main' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement | iROGeneric'.
> Property 'main' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

In addition, there is the following error message:

> This expression is not callable.
> Not all constituents of type 'HTMLElement | iROGeneric | { <K extends "object" | "textarea" | "option" | "title" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | ... 109 more ... | "wbr">(selectors: K): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]; <K extends "symbol" | ... 55 more ... | "view">(selectors: K): SVGElementTagNameMap[K]; <E extends Elemen...' are callable.
> Type 'HTMLElement' has no call signatures.

I also understand that some will be tempted with "why are you doing it this way? A better alternative would be ...". I would like to understand the use of interfaces better in order to avoid errors in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see here has little to do with recursive types and much to do with trying to access properties on a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types)-typed object.

Let's say you had a variable `something` of the following union type.

```
declare const something: HTMLElement | { prop: HTMLElement };
```

All the compiler knows about `something` is that it's *either* an `HTMLElement` *or* an object with a `prop` property of type `HTMLElement`.  If you just treat it like an `HTMLElement`, the compiler (rightfully) warns you that it doesn't know that it can be treated like one:

```
something.innerHTML.toUpperCase(); // error!
// -----> ~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type '{ prop: HTMLElement; }'
```

Read that as: "I can't tell if this is an `HTMLElement` or a `{prop: HTMLElement}`, so I can't be sure there is an `innerHTML` property."

If you want to access `innerHTML`, you need to convince the compiler that it's safe to do so.  Here's one possible way:

```
if ("style" in something) {
    something.innerHTML.toUpperCase(); // okay
}
```

By checking if `"style"` is a key of `something`, you have convinced the compiler that `something` is an `HTMLElement` and not a `{prop: HTMLElement}`, because (it assumes that) the presence of that property can be used to distinguish the two types.

---

This is exactly the problem you're having.  Imagine that you have a function that accepts an `iROGeneric<HTMLElement>`. You can't just assume its properties are `HTMLElement`s without convincing the compiler of that fact:

```
function doSomething(foo: iROGeneric<HTMLElement>) {
    Object.keys(foo).forEach(k => {
        const prop = foo[k];
        console.log(prop.tagName.toUpperCase()); // error!
    }
}
```

Instead you need to come up with a test to distinguish an `HTMLElement` from an `iROGeneric<HTMLElement>`:

```
function doSomething(foo: iROGeneric<HTMLElement>) {
    Object.keys(foo).forEach(k => {
        const prop = foo[k];
        if (prop instanceof HTMLElement) {
            console.log(prop.tagName.toUpperCase()); // okay
        } else {
            doSomething(prop); // okay
        }
    })
}
```

---

Backing up, your issue might also be that you expect the compiler to *remember* the specific structure of `Html`.  But you've *annotated* it to be of type `iROGeneric<HTMLElement>`.  Therefore the compiler dutifully forgets the *particular* structure you initialized the variable with, and *widens* its type to `iROGeneric<HTMLElement>`.  If you don't want the compiler to do that, then *don't annotate it*:

```
const Html2 = {
    body: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body")!,
    head: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("head")!,
    article: {
        main: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("main > article")!,
        aside: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("aside > article")!
    }
    oops: "sorry" // no error here
}
Html2.main.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", ""); // oops
Html2.article.main.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", ""); // okay
```

If you're worried that the compiler won't verify that `Html2` is assignable to `iROGeneric<HTMLElement>`, you should ask yourself why it matters.  If you pass it to some function that assumes it is an `iROGeneric<HTMLElement>` and it *isn't* one, you'll get an error *there*.  If you want to catch it early, though, you can make an identity helper function that checks but does not widen the type:

```
const asIROGenericHtmlElement = <T extends iROGeneric<HTMLElement>>(t: T) => t;

const Html3 = asIROGenericHtmlElement({
    body: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body")!,
    head: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("head")!,
    article: {
        main: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("main > article")!,
        aside: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("aside > article")!
    },
    oops: "sorry" // error!
//  ~~~~ <-- string is not HTMLElement | iROGeneric<HTMLElement>
})
```

Hey, an error: let's fix it:

```
const Html3 = asIROGenericHtmlElement({
    body: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body")!,
    head: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("head")!,
    article: {
        main: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("main > article")!,
        aside: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("aside > article")!
    },
//  oops: "sorry" // comment this out
})
Html3.article.main.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", ""); // okay
```

The `Html3` solution is generally the best of both worlds: the compiler remembers the exact properties and types of your object without widening, while still complaining if it doesn't conform to the widened type.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAmAJQPIHEImsBAHgBUA+ZAbwChlbkoI4ATAexABsBPZAbQGsInAFzIAzmCigA5gF0RxZAB9UmHHklEyAbioBfHVQRtxyABJgAtuxHpsufEVPEAsgBkAouwgXcYcgF5KGjoAIxYmYWRWBABXH3AAOgBHGOhOAGUILwQwFihCJzdPb19SAAoAIjCIioBKAEIAGmDaAAtGJhFouN9k1KgMrIgcvIKXDy94v0r25jqmluQ4KDACLxFqOi3kCzhQLpZYqb60zOzc-MKJkvByit3QZHJl1YQveebtujhRYCYIA5HXopU5DEaXcbFKZ3H5-FDPFZrCDzRa6PRUDH-N7LFBGEAmUQsHxgVrSERXKG+JSUZAABygLFp5Mhkyp+iohOJpJAUgSoHUVwSuQAqrTadAAMI-CBlWpaZAAegVyGgDKg9SoSuQAFpdbryAA-I3G42a5UABQZ4pW3AA5PzoFdbVEWBBRMgQCwwCqAB7AExsZBgTji5C2ih0q3Moqs8Dy3S2jHAGDISriTjvVAgMREiAk6S1IJbTl57m8h1QQUisWS6Wy+Valh8OCcdEwGIgHLAQOsdK5-M8sowFgsGyqewaMYxm5+QubOgYEIAK2GYASAk4oiHI9qCWHUHciFaZT4yH85HnXzxJnpjLPyGHLH4Mh0X1oWuvLC8CXYLCkZVvWkhTgKQADk4B8IUWFFa0pVEGVajlRVlVVPINUWLZk1TQCs3EOBOwgFgUwpWMwDnDC30-b9f3-QDgLAiCICgmDa3g2U5Qo2hdBVdh4KLN8tl7fsywAq0OIEtEtl0WoMW4mgMWvb1zCsAAme9L2QapIm6Y4QQGM5V1GEiZzuLSPkWWZOhdIFEj0wZziMlkTJmDpzK2F4kQ2Tidj2EBAR6Wz+nswyIWnaFKgebMEVed4Gk+N9YX+fzdKCgzwSna5woqRL4SWRE3mRBpUXi2gR1pUQRAqQkoAGCpkI9FgVRqvJkHaBh0WU9gVISSK+XxaAwAAQSYJdEF8K5KhCCB9wgKapFACpGmQCo6gbZUytEKhOu6jyCp63y+vglZhtGpBwAmqppryWaIHmkBFuW1b6qbFsFOMb0fgASXHdQCE6ylwHvEhfUgEAmHdWw1AcDKAb8cowHkQtzyDAxFLMSx2AAZnvL6focf7SLKDStOS4FUrBC4YdI0zwk4Ny6Es0nAtBBzQsy0oXLmOLFl29Z+K+SKmbXOy0sp4yssip48piwqFgEnKhZOfSKccsKOey35-il3nZeKs1SsZCrluq2r6tQ9V9eQE1kEIXUxAkaRUHdT0lKcqZqUhicCCpky9BkzrMYSHX9tAQ6BpOsbzvGSaroYOaFqWlakMbZtOCAA)

Answer (score 0):

```
const Html: iROGeneric<HTMLElement> = {
    body: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body"),
    head: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("head"),
    article: {
        main: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("main > article"),
        aside: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("aside > article")
    }
}
```

This looks good except `article` type, instead you should prefer this:

```
const Html: iROGeneric<HTMLElement> = {
    body: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body"),
    head: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("head"),
    article: IArticle<HTMLElement>
}

interface  IArticle<HTMLElement> {
     main: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("main > article"),
     aside: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("aside > article")
}
```

You should always define separate interfaces for nested objects and it is the only way to go. Hope you'll find this helpful and define you interfaces accordingly for future.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. With complex object structures, however, many interfaces would then have to be declared. Could the generic interface be used? Like article: {…} as iROGeneric<HTMLElement>

Comment: It is the process that we cannot ignore, you have to define so many interfaces. But it is a good thing though if you used that structure within 100s of interfaces and if you want to add one more property, then it would be a headache. That's why it is not allowed that way. And latter part, I never tried that and I would suggest you to create separate interfaces for a good practice.

Comment: Your `IArticle` interface is not valid TypeScript and it's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  Consider testing your code in a TypeScript IDE like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ymAJQW) and be sure you know that what you're suggesting makes sense and works.

Comment: Yup it won't, correct one should be this -

interface IArticle<T> {
     main: document.querySelector<T>("main > article"),
     aside: document.querySelector<T>("aside > article")
}

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.  You can't call functions inside interface definitions, and you can't set the `article` property of `Html` to a *type*.  You should really try *testing* your code in an IDE before you post it.  The compiler should be telling you this stuff, not other people on Stack Overflow.  I gave a link above that shows you what's going on.